# Way to power a monitor that requires 12 V 2.5 amps with a PC USB port

Tags: voltage, current, usb, dc, converter

I am looking to see if there is a way to power a monitor like this: ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07774L6TT/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07774L6TT)) over one (or two) of the PC's USB ports, so theoretically it would be a two wire setup, 1 HDMI, 1 USB for the whole display, no need for an extra wall outlet. I have seen USB 5 V to 12 V step-up cables but they seem to only deliver 2 amps which it looks like this monitor may need 2.5 amps.

Comment: Without complicated USB Power Delivery circuitry, USB can provide a maximum of 5V×500mA = 2.5 W of power. Your monitor requires 12V×2.5A = 30 W. I trust you see the problem there.

Comment: No, no, and no.  Your computer should at most *control* the motor, not power it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton As I understand it, some pre-ATX computer power supplies had a passthrough to provide power to the monitor as well. Not to mention that laptops power the monitor from the internal battery as well. So it's not unheard of for the power to a monitor to pass through the computer first.

Comment: A very new subset of USB-C can deliver such power. There actually exist monitors that combine both power and video delivery into a single USB-C cable.

Comment: @vini_i The specification is allowing this, but I doubt PC USB ports will be able to deliver it anyway

Comment: @vini_i That's the USB Power Delivery that I mentioned above. It's still a new enough thing that I doubt many computers support it and from the sound of it this person's monitor doesn't support it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The purpose of the power delivery standard is to be able to power such things as printers, scanners, and other peripherals such as monitors. This implies that they eventually will be able to do this.

Comment: @vini_i I think EugeneSh. 's point is that just because a standard **permits** something doesn't necessarily mean that every USB port or even every computer will **actually** support that feature.

Comment: @Hearth a mains *passthrough* is just wire, nothing like the *power supply* your monitor requires.

Comment: @ChrisStratton That's true.

Comment: I've never seen a USB(1-3) that can output 6.25 amps. You can get headers that trigger USB-PD profiles for a couple bucks on ebay.